# UTL_FILE.FOPEN Handling in oracle 18c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

Starting in Oracle Database 18c, the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter is no longer supported.
Instead, name of a directory object need to be specified.

Eg: file_open() creates an object p_target_dir_obj.

where should the p_target_dir_obj be deleted?

Sample PLSQL Code:

```
FUNCTION file_open(p_target_dir     IN VARCHAR2,
                  p_file_name      IN VARCHAR2,
                  p_write          IN BOOLEAN)
 RETURN t_file
IS
 BEGIN
 CREATE DIRECTORY p_target_dir_obj AS p_target_dir  --Created Dir object
    -- open file
      RETURN UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_target_dir_obj, p_file_name, 'W', 2001);
  END file_open;


PROCEDURE trial() 
IS
BEGIN 
p_error_file := file_open(p_debug_dir,file_name, TRUE);
UTL_FILE.fclose(p_error_file);
END
```

Can the object be destroyed at the end of file_open function or during the fclose() which is at the end of trial()
Is the object creation required only for passing to UTL_FILE.FOPEN ?

Note:Please ignore if any syntax error

Comment: You wouldn't normally create directory objects at runtime, you'd do that once as a maintenance task and then grant privileges on the directory object to the users who need to access it. Your pseudocode *sugests* you're letting end users pass in an arbitrary path they want to access, which rather circumvents the security that directory objects provide.